# Check an expresion including a dot

Tags: r, string

First of all sorry if the question is repeated, I did not find an answer to this question.
I want to get a logical vector indicating it each word of `v`'s vector contains ".x" in its name, where the dot is a part of the evaluated text. When I run this code:

```
# Vector with names
  v <- c("extra", "file.x", "file.y")
# Does v's words contain ".x" text?
 grepl(".x", v)
```

I get `TRUE TRUE FALSE`, so I think in `".x"` the dot means that there is anything before the `x` and  what I want is the dot as an string. How can I deal with taht?

This is motivated because after using `merge` function repeated columns appear with that extension.

Comment: The period has a special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape with a backslash. Try `grepl("\\.x", v)` or `grepl(".x", v, useBytes = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you so much! So `"\\.x"` specifies the dot is a part of the sting.

Comment: Yes, see the linked duplicate answer for more details.